# IOException: StreamClosed Without Apparent Cause

Tags: java, bufferedinputstream

I have created a program in Java that I want packaged into an executable jar file. I want this program to take images from the jar file and display them. I created an abstract class with a method to take a String filename and return an Image object. However, when I try to run this method, it fails and produces an "IOException: Stream closed" error.

I can't find anything on why the stream is closed. I don't have any other input streams in my program, as far as I know. Using the method in a new main with nothing but a JFrame set-up still produces the same error.

Whether I call the image file only by its name (i.e. "example.png") or use its relative path (i.e. "/src/icons/example.png"), OR use its absolute path (i.e. "C:/Users/My_Name/Desktop/EXAMPLE/src/icons/example.png") I receive the same stream closed error.

```
public static Image importImage(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Image img = null;

    byte[] data = new byte[10000];

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(      Thread.currentThread().getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName));

    int byteRead = bis.read(data, 0, 10000);

    img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(data);

    return img;
}
```

I expect the program to accept the name of the image file in question, and return an Image object. The image file is on the project's classpath, and should be visible.

Comment: Because `Thread.currentThread().getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)` is probably returning `null`

Comment: If 'Thread.currentThread().getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)' returns null, what should I use instead? The compiler pulls an error if I just use getClass() because it's a static call of a non-static method, and the compiler pulls an error if I use DEHCImager.class.getResourceAsStream(FileName) or Main.class.etc etc, saying that I don't have a 'main' method

Comment: You're free to use whatever you want, but you need to figure out what resource name to pass so that it actually finds your image file.

Comment: If that's the case, could you point me to some website or guide for finding the name of the resource?

Comment: Try this `java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream​(String name)`. Also open resource in `try (InputStream is = ...) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So as it turns out, a method like this has two requirements: One, you have to call 'thisClassName.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName).' Exactly like that. You also need to have your fileName start with '/' or it will completely not work. But, as long as the resources you are looking for are included in your program's classpath, it **should** work from there.